# Map list to tuples of following elements

Tags: kotlin

I have given a list of integers. I need to map always two following elements in further progressing. If the input list contains a invalid count of elements the last ones should be dropped. Here is an example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] //Input
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)] //Output
```

I wrote to functions to get the wanted output but I think they are both inefficient.

First i tried it with a functional approach. But it needs two filter calls and a zip call for the resulting list. So it iterates 2.5 times over the entier list.

Two imrpove this I tried a iterative approach. It only iterates once over the list and is possibly the fastest version. But it uses multiple mutable variables/lists. Also it is not as easy to understand as the functinal approach. (And it breaks the cleaness of the rest of the code)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    mapFunctional()
    mapIterative()
}

fun mapFunctional() {
    val list: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

    val output: List<Pair<Int, Int>> = list.filterIndexed { index, _ ->
        index % 2 == 0
    }.zip(list.filterIndexed {
        index, _ -> index % 2 == 1
    })

    println(output)
}

fun mapIterative() {
    val list: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

    val output: MutableList<Pair<Int, Int>> = mutableListOf()
    var index = 0
    while (index < list.size - 1) {
        output.add(list[index++] to list[index++])
    }

    println(output)
}
```

Is their a good (efficient) way to achieve this in a functinal aprroach or is it only possible with a classic loop?

Comment: Sorry for the bad title. I don't know how to correctly call this procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a `List<Pair>`, you can use a standard library call for this called [`windowed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html).

```
val myList = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val listOfPairs = myList.windowed(2, 2).map { Pair(it[0], it[1]) }
// [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

The `windowed` function will return a `List<List<Int>>`, so you'll have to map the internal `List<Int>` to a `Pair<Int, Int>`. The `windowed` function by default will drop partial windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard library function [`.chunked(n)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) for this purpose:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val output = list.chunked(2).dropLastWhile { it.size < 2 }
```

<sup>As `chunked` preserves the last partial list containing less items than the required size, you need to handle this and drop it conditionally with [`.dropLastWhile { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop-last-while.html)</sup>